# Сортировка таблицы, помогите разобрать как реализовать.

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как сделать задачу:

> При клике на ячейки шапки таблицы должны происходить сортировка по
>   соответствующему полю. Дополнение - 1-ый клик сортировка asc, 2-ой
>   клик сортировка desc. Визуально с помощью стрелочки отобразить
>   направление активной сортировки. Методы сортировки не должны
>   перезагружать страницу. В урл после сортировки должны записываться
>   сортировочные параметры. При открытии полученной ссылки в браузере
>   изначальные данные должны сортироваться в соответствии значений в
>   ссылке.

В частности не могу понять как сделать:

> методы сортировки не должны перезагружать страницу. В урл после
>   сортировки должны записываться сортировочные параметры. При открытии
>   полученной ссылки в браузере изначальные данные должны сортироваться в
>   соответствии значений в ссылке.

Т.е параметры просто записываются в url, но на сервер не отсылаются? А отсылаются только при вводе url? Возможно ли реализовать такое? Какой в этом смысл?  Может проще было бы сортировку сделать в базе данных? Спасибо

Comment: Вас просят сделать ajax. При запросе перерисовываете только таблицу с данными + записываете в url запрос который отправляли ajax'ом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> При клике на ячейки шапки таблицы должны происходить сортировка по соответствующему полю. Дополнение - 1-ый клик сортировка asc, 2-ой клик сортировка desc. Визуально с помощью стрелочки отобразить направление активной сортировки. Методы сортировки не должны перезагружать страницу.

Выполняете сортировку либо средствами браузерного скрипта либо посредством AJAX запроса на сервер (предпочтительно).

> В урл после сортировки должны записываться сортировочные параметры. При открытии полученной ссылки в браузере изначальные данные должны сортироваться в соответствии значений в ссылке.

С помощью *HTML5 History API* изменяете историю таким образом, словно пользователь перешел по адресу с предустановленными параметрами сортировки.  Само собой, сервер должен корректно отрабатывать такую ссылку и выдавать страницу с уже отсортированными данными.
https://astrio.ru/blog/History-API/
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API

> Т.е параметры просто записываются в url, но на сервер не отсылаются? А отсылаются только при вводе url?

Если сортировать будете уже полученные данные на клиенте, то не отсылаются. Если реализуете AJAX API, будете отсылать параметры в AJAX запросе.

> Возможно ли реализовать такое? Какой в этом смысл?

Возможно. Смысл в том, чтобы при работе с сайтом иметь минимум задержек, связанных с перезагрузкой страницы. И, в тоже время, сохранить возможность перехода к определенному состоянию сайта по прямой ссылке.

> Может проще было бы сортировку сделать в базе данных?

Как вашей душе угодно.